# Is there a way to use a TestNG DataProvider outside of one's Test classes?

Tags: testing, testng

A TestNG test class can become pretty bloated if every test uses its own DataProvider. Is there anyway to import these from another Java class (ie: one where constants are already declared)? I could not find any existing documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Data Providers in an another class (not in the same class having test methods) like below and refer it using dataProviderClass in Test annotation

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class DataProviderClass  { //Data Provider class

    @DataProvider(name = "data-provider")
    public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
      return new Object[][] { { "1" }, { "2" } };
    }
}
```

TestClass.java

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

     @Test(dataProvider = "data-provider", dataProviderClass = DataProviderClass.class)
     public void testMethod(String data) {
        System.out.println("Data is: " + data);
     }
}
```